# Prevent regular users from accessing Windows settings

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, administrator, control-panel, user-groups

I have two user accounts under `Windows 10 Pro` (version 2004) - one administrative and the other regular. I would like to forbid the access to the Windows settings from the regular account. In particular, I am interested in blocking the network proxy settings as shown in [this video](https://youtu.be/rzQKDzpMScI).

I tried doing this by running `gpedit.msc`, going `User Configuration`->`Administrative Settings` -> `Control Panel`, double-clicking `Prohibit access to Control Panel and PC settings` and choosing the `Enabled` option. I did this while logged into the regular account (which temporarily had the administrative privileges). However, that made settings inaccessible for the administrative user as well.

Additional information based on the comments:

- The computer is not part of AD or any other IT environment.
- `Computer Configuration` –> `Administrative Templates` –> `Control Panel` -> `Settings Page Visibility` is not configured.

So, how can I prevent only regular users from accessing the Windows settings?

Comment: What group policies did you try exactly?  You should [edit] your question in order to provide this vital information.

Comment: @John - The author wants to configure a proxy but prevent users from disabling it.

Comment: @Ramhound I have edited the question to detail what I did more precisely.

Comment: I am guessing this machine is NOT connected to a AD domain?  What is the current configuration of the `Prevent changing proxy settings` policy?

Comment: @Ramhound Since this is the first time I hear about AD and it is a home computer, I assume not.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - You need to be able to provide the answer if this machine is connected to an Active Directory domain.  What solutions will be possible will depend on that fact.  Please be sure to [edit] the question to include that vital information about the group policy.

Comment: As you are provide the necessary information to answer this question.  Be sure to provide us the current values of `Computer Configuration –> Administrative Templates –> Control Panel -> Settings Page Visibility`.  You probably want to use something like `showonly:windowsupdate;bluetooth;printers;mouse`

Comment: @Ramhound I have edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a away to edit the local group policy , and make it apply to all the users except the local administrators.
Open the the group policy object edit through mmc:

[image]
[image]
[image]
In the MMC Console window, click on File (Menu bar) and Save As.
Select to save to your Desktop, type in a name (ex: Non-Administrators-Group-Policy) that you would like to have for this "all users except administrators" group policy MSC file, then click on the Save button.
Then when you edit the local group policy through this file, it will apply to all users except administrators.
For more details you can refer to:
https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/101869-local-group-policies-apply-all-users-except-administrators.html